# The security token included in the request is invalid. aws js sdk

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I posted [here on the AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=217253&tstart=0)

I'm using the aws-js-sdk v2.2.3 with the following code.  I get data back with Credentials populated.  When I try to use the credentials I get the error that they are invalid. I'm using the developer authenticated identities flow. I have both roles Auth & UnAuth. My identity pool looks like it's correct.  The trust relationships look like they are pointing to the correct identity pool id.  There are policies attached to the Auth role for S3 & DynamoDB.  I'm at a loss.  Any help would be appreciated.

javascript client side:

```
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({region: 'us-east-1'});
    var params = {
      IdentityId: user.cognito_id,
      Logins: {
    'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': user.cognito_token
      }
    };
    cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else console.log(data.Credentials);
    });
```

I console.log the Id & SecretKey and they are filled in.

```
var aws_creds = StateService.get('user').aws_creds;
console.log(aws_creds.AccessKeyId);
console.log(aws_creds.SecretKey);
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: aws_creds.AccessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: aws_creds.SecretKey,
            endpoint: ENV.aws_dyndb_endpoint,
            region: 'us-east-1'
            });
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();


console.log("user obj: ", StateService.get('user'));
var params = {
    TableName: games_table_name,
    KeyConditionExpression: "Id = :v1",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":v1": {"N": id}
    }
};

return dynamodb.query(params);
```

**My Solution**
What I came up with was to explicitly refresh the credentials versus get them lazily when I created a DynamoDb object for instance. Here's the function I use which returns a promise & resolves when the credentials are refreshed.

```
refresh: function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; 
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID, 
      IdentityId: COGNITO_ID, 
      Logins: 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com'
    });

    AWS.config.credentials.refresh(function(error) {
      if ((error === undefined) || (error === null)) {
        $log.debug("Credentials Refreshed Success: ", AWS.config.credentials);
        var params = {
          region: 'us-east-1',
          apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
          credentials: AWS.config.credentials
        };

        $rootScope.dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({params: params});
        deferred.resolve();
      }
      else {
        $log.debug("Error refreshing AWS Creds:, ", error);
        deferred.reject(error);
      }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that saves the response from getCredentialsForIdentity()? And where is the code that actually uses those credentials in an operation that fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Cognito credentials to call other AWS services, I recommend you use the high-level `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` object from the Javascript SDK, instead of calling the service API directly.

You can find more information about how to initialize and use `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` in the Cognito Developer Guide: 
[Developer Authenticated Identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/?platform=javascript)

Albert

Comment: I'm having the same problem using the CognitoIdentityCredentials object as well.  Ultimately it still errors with the security token being invalid.

Comment: @StephenBurke did you ever figure out your issue with this error? I'm getting the invalid security token error also

Comment: @BenDavis I edited the original post with my solution.  There is also more info in the AWS forums link that's at the top.  Ultimately for me I needed to set a region & also explicitly refresh the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

The flow is like this: You ask the `CognitoIdentityCredentials` for a `IdentityId`, the IDentityId is supposed to track users accross devices and across Identities providers like (Facebook, Google, TWitter, etc.) then you with that ID you ask for a role attached to your pole `CognitoIdentity`, after you get the token, you ask the `STS.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity` for a temporary credentials with the appropriate roles attached to your pole.

Here is an example of how I did it:

```
// set the Amazon Cognito region
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

// initialize the Credentials object with our parameters
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:YMIDENTITYPOLEID',
});

// We can set the get method of the Credentials object to retrieve
// the unique identifier for the end user (identityId) once the provider
// has refreshed itself
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error: "+err);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Cognito Identity Id: " + AWS.config.credentials.identityId);

        params = {
            IdentityId: AWS.config.credentials.identityId
        }

    // Other service clients will automatically use the Cognito Credentials provider
    // configured in the JavaScript SDK.

        // Get the Role associated with the id coming from the pool
        var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();

        cognitoidentity.getOpenIdToken(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            }else{
                        // Get temporoarly credientials form STS to access the API
                        var params = {
                            RoleArn: 'ROLE_OF_YOUR_POLE_ARN', /* required */
                            RoleSessionName: 'WHATEVERNAME', /* required */
                            WebIdentityToken: data.Token, /* required */
                        };

                        var sts = new AWS.STS()

                        console.log(data);           // successful response
                        console.log(data.Token)

                        sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
                                if (err){
                                        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                                }else{
                                        console.log(data);           // successful response
                                        // Now we need these credentials that we got for this app and for this user
                                        // From here we can limit the damage by
                                        // Burst calling to the API Gateway will be limited since we now that this is a single user on a single device
                                        // If suspicious activities we can drop this user/device
                                        // The privileges are limited since the role attached to this is only the API GateWay calling
                                        // This creds are temporary they will expire in 1h

                                        var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
                                            accessKey: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
                                            secretKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                                            sessionToken: data.Credentials.Token, //OPTIONAL: If you are using temporary credentials you must include the session token
                                            region: AWS.config.region // OPTIONAL: The region where the API is deployed, by default this parameter is set to us-east-1
                                        });

                                        // Call the get to test
                                        apigClient.deviceGet({}, {})
                                    .then(function(result){
                                        //This is where you would put a success callback
                                                console.log(result)
                                    }).catch( function(result){
                                        //This is where you would put an error callback
                                    });

                                }
                        });
            }
        });

});
```

NB: This was a test to get access to the API Gateway service, but it is not different to get access to other services, it depends on the pole you configure it and its attached services.

If you have credential for a user created in IAM you don't need the temporary token, but if you use this flow you have to include it.

Another point, limit the access to the services on your pole, keep in mind that is a publicly given key, every one can use it to get access to your stuff.

STS.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity is used because we are on the web, in the AWS JS SDK, if you use iOS or android/java or Boto, you have to use STS.assumeRole.

Hope this helps.